# Detect when a socket io connection has been changed with ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, socket.io

Im using ember with socket.io and I want a computed property that changes to if the socket io connection is connected or disconnected.

I am using ember-websockets and here is what I have tried:

```
socketIOService: service('socket-io'),
socketRoute:     'http://localhost:8080/',

connected: computed('socketIOService',
function()
{
    console.log('changed!');
    //return (this.get('socketIOService').socketFor(this.get('socketRoute').socket.connected));
}),

startConnection()
{
    this.get('connected');
    const socket = this.socketIOService.socketFor(this.get('socketRoute'));

    socket.on('initialised', this.initialised, this);
},
```

So this doesnt work because im guessing the service doesnt change. I would like to be able to computer a value from the following...

this.socketIOService.socketFor(this.get('socketRoute'));

But I cant get the sockerFor property in a computed property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [readme](https://github.com/thoov/ember-websockets), I think you can use 'open' and 'close' events, w/co computed properties:

```
startConnection()
{
    const socket = this.socketIOService.socketFor(this.get('socketRoute'));
    socket.on('open', () => { this.set('connected', true); });
    socket.on('close', () => { this.set('connected', false); });
}
```

Comment: This didnt work, As far as i know socket.on just initalises a listener and theres no reserved names for connected or disconnected.

Comment: @RachelDockter in example from ember-websockets [repo](https://github.com/thoov/ember-websockets) it shows that there are `open` and `close` events

Comment: thats strange, i dont know why its not working for me then

Comment: I just tried a load of names and 'connect' and 'disconnect' seem to be working instead of open and close. Thanks :)

Comment: @RachelDockter after looking into sources I see why is that - `ember-websockets` provides two services, `socket-io` and `websockets`. Both have `socketFor` method but it returns different type of `socket` objects. In your case (`socket-io` service) it's [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md#socket) and it indeed has `connect` and `disconnect` events instead of `open` and `close`